# Simple SQL Query to count poll results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best and efficient way to count poll results from PollResponses table for a particular PollId as per db schema shown below

[image]

I want to have following type of Data if we have four option for that particular poll

```
optionText
count
optiontext
count
optiontext
count
optiontext
count
```

Example

```
Obama
2000
Romney
1800
Clinton
3000
Xyz
1200
```

total 8 rows fetched

I am using SQL Server 2012 sp1 update

using below query

```
select options.OptionText as [optionText]
,count(responses._id) as [count]
from Polls polls
inner join PollOptions options on options.PollId = polls._id
inner join PollResponses responses on responses.PollId = polls._id
where polls._id = 104
group by options.OptionText, polls._id
```

with this data of pollresponse table
[image]

i m getting this result

[image]

while i should get
No 0
Yes 1

current data of all three tables

1. Polls

[image]

2. PollOptions

[image]

3. PollResponse

[image]

Comment: Can you post data from each of your tables?

Comment: Hello, can you post what the other 2 tables look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will return the result you want:

```
select po.optiontext,
  count(pr.optionid) Total
from PollOptions po
left join polls p
  on p._id = po.pollid
left join pollresponse pr
  on p._id = pr.pollid
  and pr.optionid = po._id
-- where p._id = 104
group by po.optiontext;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33efe/24)

Based on the sample data you provided the result will be:

```
| OPTIONTEXT | TOTAL |
----------------------
|     HOD IT |     1 |
|   HOD Mech |     1 |
|     Mr. CS |     2 |
|         no |     0 |
|        yes |     1 |
```

Edit, if you want to order the data by option id, then you will have to include it in the `group by`:

```
select po.optiontext,
  count(pr.optionid) Total
from PollOptions po
left join polls p
  on p._id = po.pollid
left join pollresponse pr
  on p._id = pr.pollid
  and pr.optionid = po._id
--where p._id = 104
group by po.optiontext, po._id
order by po._id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33efe/29)

Results:

```
| OPTIONTEXT | TOTAL |
----------------------
|     Mr. CS |     2 |
|     HOD IT |     1 |
|   HOD Mech |     1 |
|        yes |     1 |
|         no |     0 |
```

Comment: hey your sql also is not returning a row with "no" and 0 as count , i think this simple looking task is becoming more interesting :)

Comment: try running with p._id = 104      , then it should return yes 1 and No 0 .

Comment: @AbhishekGupta see my edit, I changed the order of the joins and it appears to be working for all polls. :)

Comment: yes it is working now but i think i should order by with optionid also because no is appearing first then yes , while yes should come before and then no

Comment: @AbhishekGupta you just need to add an `order by` clause but the value you order by must be added to the `group by`.  See my edit

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have your data to work with, here's a VERY rough (i.e. untested) idea of what you should be doing.  You essentially `INNER JOIN` your tables and then use the aggregate function `COUNT` to count all the responses for each grouped candidate.

```
select options.OptionText as [optionText]
,count(responses._id) as [count]
from Polls polls
inner join PollOptions options on options.PollId = polls._id
inner join PollResponses responses on responses.PollId = polls._id
where polls._id = @pollid
group by options.OptionText, polls._id
```

Relating to efficiency, I can see you're using primary keys and foreign key constraints; another performance improvement you could make would be to index your `OptionText` column on your `PollOptions` table.

Comment: working fine but i want to add where clause also in it because i want to fetch results for a particular pollId

Comment: @AbhishekGupta have added the `WHERE` clause to the query

Comment: I facing one problem regarding accuracy of this solution posting screen shot shortly

Comment: please see the updated question your query results are mentioned there

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    po.OptionText AS [optionText],
    COUNT(pr._id) AS [count]
FROM PollResponses pr
JOIN Polls p ON (p._id = pr.PollID)
JOIN PollOptions po ON (po.PollID = p._id)
WHERE p._id = @pPollId
GROUP BY po.OptionText, pr._id
```

Comment: sorry results not proper , moreover we have to pass PollId = @pPollId like this in where query

Comment: Edited to include the input parameter, can you describe the result set you're seeing?

Comment: result are 12 rows with count 1 while it should be 4 rows with count of it

Answer (score 0):

I believe the query you have written is missing a join . . . which is also missing from the ER diagram you show.  However, the results table has an OptionID.  Presumably, there are multiple options for a given poll.  So try this:

```
select options.OptionText as [optionText], polls._id, count(responses._id) as [count]
from Polls polls inner join
     PollOptions options
     on options.PollId = polls._id inner join
     PollResponses responses
     on responses.PollId = polls._id and responses.OptionId = options._Id
where polls._id = 104
group by options.OptionText, polls._id
```

If responses and options are not connected, then you cannot directly get the number of responses for each option.

Comment: above query is not showing row which has count 0 against it even after adding missing relationship as said by you